R shiny: how to trigger either onRestored or an observer
Having following app with two Inputs, while the second is depended on the first one and is updated on the server site. How to implement bookmarking in such a way that the second variable (Input2) is updated only once when restoring the site using a link?
df <- structure(list(Input1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
                          "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Input2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
                          5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                          "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
                           Input1 = c("A", "B", "C"), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:10,  11:15), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                           "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))

shinyApp(
  ui = function(request) {fluidPage(
    selectInput("input1", "input1", choices = unique(df$Input1)),
    selectInput("input2", "input2", choices = NA)
  )},
  server = function(input, output, session){
    observe({
      req(input$input1)
      
      tmp_input2 <- df %>% 
        filter(Input1 == input$input1) %>% 
        pull(Input2)
      updateSelectInput(session, "input2", choices = tmp_input2)
    })
    
    
    observe({
     session$doBookmark()
    })
    onBookmarked(function(url) {
      updateQueryString(url)
    })
    
    onRestored(function(state) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected = state$input$input2)
      })
    
    
    observe({
      print(input$input2)
    })
    
  },enableBookmarking = "url")

When restoring the website using e.g. this link http://127.0.0.1:6279/?_inputs_&input1=%22A%22&input2=%225%22
then you can observe in the console that first the observer is triggered than the onRestore. This is no problem in this app, but mine triggeres here an event which needs some time and since it is fired twice (observer, than onRestored) the user ecperience is two times decreased.
I tried to use a logical vector (restored) which is set to TRUE inside the onRestored function, but without success.
Setting a req(restored) inside the observer works when restoring, but of course is failing when the website is started blank.
onRestore, since it is triggered before all observeres, would be perfect, but since Input1 is needed to "calculate" Input2 this is not possible.

onRestore is the way to go. The issue is, that you can't define a selected value in updateSelectInput, which isn't present in the choices (please see the modified onRestored call):
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

DF <- structure(list(Input1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
                          "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Input2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
                          5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L)), class = c("grouped_DF", 
                          "tbl_DF", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
                           Input1 = c("A", "B", "C"), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:10,  11:15), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                           "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_DF", "tbl", "data.frame")))

shinyApp(
  ui = function(request) {
    fluidPage(
      selectInput("input1", "input1", choices = unique(DF$Input1)),
      selectInput("input2", "input2", choices = NA)
    )
  },
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    restored_session <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
    observe({
      if(!restored_session()){
        req(input$input1)
        tmp_input2 <- DF %>%
          filter(Input1 == input$input1) %>%
          pull(Input2)
        updateSelectInput(session, "input2", choices = tmp_input2) 
      }
    })
    # observe({
    #   session$doBookmark()
    # })
    onBookmarked(function(url) {
      updateQueryString(url)
    })
    onRestore(function(state) {
      restored_session(TRUE)
    })
    onRestored(function(state) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "input2", choices = state$input$input2, selected = state$input$input2)
    })
    observe({
      print(input$input2)
    })
  },
  enableBookmarking = "url"
)


Very nice. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Is there a way to show the url in the browser? Unfortunatly, the app is frozen after restoring. The input 2 isn't working. Since restored_session() is FALSE. Where to set it to TRUE?

I don't understand the question. Would you like to update the url once an input was changed? If so please find an example here: ?updateQueryString

I activated again the session$doBookmark() and added restored_session(FALSE) inside the onRestored(function(state). Now its working! Thanks
